# Onboarding individuals (natural persons) with Stripe Connect

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am building a C2C marketplace with PHP/Laravel/Laravel-cashier for used sport gear with some sort of buyer protection feature. To facilitate payments and transfer funds I am using Stripe Payments & Stripe Connect. My issue is about onboarding the seller with Connect, specifically in Germany. I am using the Express Account option to avoid dealing with any sensitive data. Even tho I am already passing to Stripe that I would like to onboard a individual user (in a sense of a natural person, not an individual business), the user still has to select a business type (freelancer, corporation, stock corporation, assosciation)

Here is the payload I am sending to Stripe when redirecting a user to the Connect onboarding:

```
$stripe->accounts->create([
  'type' => 'express',
  'business_type' => 'individual',
  'business_profile' => ['url' => 'https://example.com'],
]);
```

I played around with adding and removing capabilities, but the result stayed the same.

```
$stripe->accounts->create([
  'type' => 'express',
  'capabilities' => [
    'transfers' => ['requested' => true],
  ],
  'business_type' => 'individual',
  'business_profile' => ['url' => 'https://example.com'],
]);`
```

Also, if I remove the business_type completely, the onboarding stays exactly the same. But Stripe says, it won't ask for prefilled info again during onboarding.

> Connect Onboarding won’t ask for the prefilled information during account onboarding
> https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts

Should there not be a difference in onboarding if I provide or not provide the business_type?

Is it not possible to use Stripe Connect for this C2C use case? My implementation does work for business users.

Comment: When I make similar request with prefilled `business_type` the onboarding flow does not ask me to re-confirm this. It sounds like something unexpected might be happening for you, and I would suggest you reach out to Stripe support: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: @NolanH quick update: I got in contact with Stripe support and they told me that the business_type question is always included in the onboarding flow. Just to be double sure: when you created the onboarding link and onboarded, it still asked you the business type but it was prefilled, right? It was not removed from the flow. Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

The onboarding page that includes the 'country' and 'type of business' menus won't show if both of the following is done:
-You set the `business_type`
-You request `capabilities`

I'm surprised it didn't work for you with `capabilities` set, as it works for me, using the very same code you have. Might depend on the platform origin, both US and IE work for me.
What country is your platform based in ? Can you test it with `capabilities` again, as well as requesting both `transfers` and `card_payments` ?

Comment: After going back and forth with Stripe, we found a solution. It's never mentioned in the docs (I think) but you have to provide the country as well as business_type & capabilities in the request. The moment you provide the country, it won't ask for it anymore. Kind of straightforward but the docs always just talked about providing the business_type. Platform is based in the EU (Italy). Not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: Weird - the `country` defaults to your platform's if not set. Anyway good to know !